# Node.js + Express form validation with Flash + Express-Validator

Tags: node.js, forms, express, passport.js, express-validator

I have an HTML form that I want to validate on my site and it is *NOT* a login form.

It is a simple HTML form:

```
  <form method= "post">
    <div id= bookingFields>
      <label>Name</label> <input class = "userInfo" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
      <label>Email</label> <input class = "userInfo" id="email" name="email" type="text"/>
      <label>Guests</label> <input class = "userInfo" id="guestCount" name="guestCount" type="number" min="1" max="8"/>
      <label>Date</label> <input class = "userInfo" id="dateRange" name="dateRange" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Request to Book">
    <div>
  </form>
```

The site is for booking a vacation home, so the only fields I need to validate are if the name is greater than 2 characters, and if the email is a valid email address...thats it. I also have [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/) running a calendar of available dates that I'd *maybe* like to integrate into the date picker field, but I'm not going to worry about that right now.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I would like the user to be able to fill out this form and have it be validated before posting to a MongoDB server with errors and feedback for the user to correct. I'm using Node.js + Express for my backend and I'm attempting to use `flash` to have these messages display to the user. I have ventured pretty far down this rabbit hole of `flash`,  `express-validator`, `express-session`, `passport`, `express-flash messages`, etc. and they all seem to require each other to work. But it seems as if the purpose of all of this middleware is to validate and handle a *login*, and keep the user logged in from page to page, and request to request.

Do I even need this for what I'm trying to do?

I would like to use `express-validator` because the methods for sanitization, trimming, and validating forms seem easy and straightforward. But I need `express-session` to do it, which needs `passport` to use `flash` to flash messages to the user and it just seems overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. I really just only want to use the `trim()`,`isLength()`, and `sanitizeBody()` methods on `express-validator` and use `flash` to display messages to the user. Thats all.

I don't have a login on my site and all of the forms I am trying to validate only exist on one page. Can I even use `flash` and `express-validator` for this? Is there a better way?

Heres the get/post requests in my index.js file:

```
router.get('/availibility', (req, res) => {
  res.render('availibility');
});

router.post('/availibility', passport.authenticate('local', { 
     successRedirect: '/',
     failureRedirect: '/availibility'
})
//req.check('name', 'Name must be longer than 2 letters').isLength({min:2});
//req.check('email','Must be a valid email').isEmail();
);
```

I am getting errors in my broswer saying `Unknown authentication strategy “local”`. You can see by the lines commented out that I was attempting to use `express-validator` methods to validate the forms. But that doesn't seem to work without `express-session`, which I want to use `flash` with, and all of this doesn't work without `passport`. I don't need to validate a login, so I'm wondering if I even need this or if there's a better way to go about it.

Here is my app.js file *AS IS*:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const flash = require('express-flash-messages');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password'
}, (req, username, password, done) => {
     // This was copy/pasted from another StackOverflow post that didn't answer my question
       ...
       .. 
  }));
}
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);



module.exports = app;
```

Thanks in advance!!